# What can i do on the phone?

Tags: php, android

I don't have a computer. But I'm very keen on programming. What can I do from the phone? Does anyone have experience with programming from the phone?

This happens too if it happens on the phone

PHP html Android Python Java or other languages ​​I don't know

Comment: look up the video Joma did on YouTube. He wrote most of a program on his phone in the video.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? I am using translation

Comment: Honestly, answering questions on this site with code on a phone can be cumbersome to the point that I don't do it for anything complex. Phone keyboards are always trying to fix typos based on human languages, and you pretty much have to disable spellcheck if you want to do anything really productive. Joma's tutorial is SSH'ing into a real computer to get the work done, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of web-only services where you can program and directly run the result. For example:

- JSFiddle
- CodeSandbox
- CodeAnywhere
- StackBlitz
- CodeEnvy
- Gitpod
- Theia

As you don't need anything more than a browser, you'd already be set with a phone. Most phones allow USB-to-HDMI and connecting a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard, so you could make that a pretty decent workplace after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the basics of any coding language on a phone, but if you wish to excel upon your programming skills you will need a PC, my opinion. I would suggest watching free programming courses, tutorials etc. and test your skills with some programming quizzes which you can find online quite easily. Other than that, you can check the appstore on IOS or the google playstore on Android for some programming text editors.

Have a look here https://medium.com/swlh/can-you-learn-to-code-on-your-phone-95523c7c3eeb